# "fatal error No such file or directory" in rdlibkafka

Tags: c, gcc, apache-kafka, compiler-errors, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to kafka. I downloaded [rdlibkafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka) from github and try to run [producer.c](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/producer.c) example code
but I give error.
How can I solve it?

Error:

```
[producer.c 2023-01-19 12:25:31.509]
,,producer.c:8:10: fatal error: rdkafka.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "rdkafka.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I think the problem is about compiler which cannot find rdlibkafka but I'm sure it is installed.
because header files exist in /usr/include/rdlibkafka

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and add more details. What command do you use to build the example program? The CMake build in the project repository can optionally build the examples and will probably use the correct settings.

Comment: How do you try to compile? Do you specify the include path for kafka? It seems that is missing.

Comment: Unless you are trying to write your own producer, you could use `kcat` to simply send data to Kafka... Also, maybe check out  https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka